# Testing uppercase vs lowercase field values on the fly using ArcPy & Python?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, select-by-attribute

I am trying to use the code below to allow testing of one field which contains mixed case against another field which contains uppercase only. 
I have read many many posts but they generally tend to look at converting or using Field Calc and I do not want the values to be converted. (only on the fly)
I am using ArcGIS 10.2 Win 7 x64 and Python 27.

```
    # Refine the selection set to only 'LGA <> LGA_NAME'
    fn99 = "LGA"
    fn98 = "LGA_NAME"
    EXPR1 = fn99.upper() +"<>"+ fn98.upper()
    DEF1 = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc_lyr2, "NEW_SELECTION", EXPR1)
    print "\n" "Using SelectLayerByAttribute to create a 'NEW_SELECTION' from " + fc_lyr2
    print DEF1.getMessages()
```

Note I dont get any errors, my code just doesnt test successfully so all values are retyurned and I know there are at least 50 incorrect values from manual checking.

Comment: You are uppercasing the field names (which are already in uppercase) and not the values in those fields.  I would suggest adding a field (perhaps called flag) and then use an arcpy.da.UpdateCursor to set its value to 1 (to be used to later select it) when row[0].upper() <> row[1].upper().  Then SelectLayerByAttribute just grabs flag = 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the ArcGIS help topic "SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS":

> Strings are case sensitive in expressions. For feature classes and tables, you can use the UPPER or LOWER function to set the case for a selection.

(untested) Try changing this line: `EXPR1 = "UPPER({}) <> UPPER({})".format(fn99, fn98)`

Comment: +1 UPPER keyword is the way.